# How to setup amazon s3 module on ubuntu?

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am looking at the readme and there isn't any instructions on how to install it locally on my ubuntu machine (curious, is it different on a mac os?)

http://github.com/boto/boto/blob/master/README

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a package on pypi:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/boto

Just install like any other python package using easy_install:

```
easy_install boto
```

Or download the package manually and run `python setup.py install`.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon's documentation should help. Here's the [getting started guide for S3 and Python](http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=3998&categoryID=175). It's in the cheese shop, so it's as easy as

```
sudo pip install -U boto
```

or

```
sudo easy_install boto
```